# UIWebView's Content color changed unexpectedly

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I am using mathjax for loading the mathematical function, while i am loading the html content into the `UIWebView` some of the content color will br changed into blue color,

[image]

But i load the same html content into the browser means, it is displaying correctly

[image]

Please share if anyone have any idea about this issue,

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS, Webkit tries to recognize phone numbers and turn them into links.  I'm wondering if your stacked fractions of small integers  look like phone numbers to iOS.  Are the blue ones acting as links, and if so, to what?

You can disable this phone-number-recognition feature by adding

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

to the `<head>` of your document.  Hope that takes care of it for you.